# Dask application has trouble scaling up, any suggestions?

Tags: python, dask

I have a fairly straightforward Dask application (filter a large wavefield) that I am having trouble scaling up. My job function is:

```
def filter_wavefield(pos, butter_filter,wave):
    filtered = signal.sosfilt(butter_filter,wave[pos,:]).astype("float32")
    return filtered
```

After loading the data to dask arrays (no problem scaling up here), I have tried three approaches to submit jobs:

1. Pre-scatter the data and pass the futures to the last argument of the job function

```
wave_future = client.scatter(wave_on_slice_channel,broadcast=True)

# I choose to parallelize over the coordinates, so I make several bags of those
coord_list = [i for i in range(nelem*ngll)]
coord_bag = db.from_sequence(coord_list,npartitions=500)
# Submit the tasks
filtered = coord_bag.map(filter_wavefield, butter_filter,wave_future)
filtered_waves = filtered.compute()
```

This approach works very well for data size about up to 0.5 TiB. However, now my data size is 1.35 TiB, and even this ~3 fold increase breaks things down completely. When I run `filtered_waves = filtered.compute()` with the current dataset, everything freezes (i.e. dashboard useless) and the kernel simply dies.

[image]

2. Persist the large data

I then did some research on how people deal with > 1TiB data with dask and come across [this page](https://blog.dask.org/2018/06/26/dask-scaling-limits). In the video, the dask expert `persist` the data right away. I tried this:

```
wave = wave_on_slice_channel.persist()
wait(wave)

# Same stuff about coordinates
coord_list = [i for i in range(nelem*ngll)]
coord_bag = db.from_sequence(coord_list,npartitions=500)
# Submit the tasks
filtered = coord_bag.map(filter_wavefield, butter_filter,wave)
filtered_waves = filtered.compute()
```

Note here, the last argument passed in to the job function is no longer a future, but I suppose it's actual data already persisted to the memory.

I am using 500 cores with a total of > 3.5 TiB memory, so after persisting, my dashboard looks like the following

[image]

This is all great, and I have my 1.35TiB in the distributed memory. However, everything still breaks once `filtered_waves = filtered.compute()` is called. The symptom is the same as before. Everything freezes and becomes unresponsive. Shortly after the python kernel dies.

3. Using for loop + `submit` rather than dask bags + `map`

After persisting the data, I tried to run one instance of the job function:

`signal.sosfilt(butter_filter,wave[120,:])`

and this can be ran in a split of a second, which means that accessing the large data `wave` is not causing problems. Then I tried the following:

```
filtered_futures = []
for pos in coord_list:
  filtered_futures.append(client.submit(filter_wavefield,pos,butter_filter,wave))
```

Once the last line above is ran, I do see some response on the dashboard. Most importantly, my job function `filter_wavefield` is now listed as one of the tasks being processed (previous two methods won't even get the job function into the progress bars), and the number of tasks for `filter_wavefiled` is quickly increasing. However, after it increased to about 2700, everything freezes like before. The full size of the `for` loop, i.e. the coordinate list is 27482400.

I am fairly confident that Dask is built to handle this specific application I am attempting, but I am very lost now as to what else could I try. It seems the problem lies with how I am partitioning the tasks, but I thought this is exactly what Dask bag is supposed to handle (see [here](https://examples.dask.org/applications/embarrassingly-parallel.html#Handling-very-large-simulation-with-Bags)), yet the failure of this is what's letting me to try other methods.

Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated!